# Installing Kubuntu with Manual Partitioning & Encryption

Tags: linux-mint, partition, encryption, kubuntu

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 20.04 with LVM encryption on a dual-boot machine.  Previously, I'd done this on Mint per [these simple steps](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=298852).  In brief, all you have to do setup your partitions manually during the install process: you choose "physical volume for encryption," it prompts you for the password, & creates an ext4 encrypted volume which I then set its mount point to "/" (& change to btrfs).

But in the Kubuntu installer this doesn't work.  If you select "physical volume for encryption," nothing happens. After some googling, I found [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1510731) showing that their installer has had this bug for nearly half a decade.

So the question: since it doesn't seem like the Kubuntu team will be fixing their installer anytime soon, how would one manually setup a similar partition layout - ideally in the Kubuntu live OS (prior to running the installer)?  Can the same installation result be safely achieved in this way?

And for clarity, what exactly is the Mint installer doing when you tell it to create a "physical volume for encryption," & then follow its prompts per above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out a working solution:

1) Follow the extremely thorough instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption/DetailedProcessPartition)...

2) ...But instead of using his installation script, grab the btrfs-friendly alternative from [here](https://github.com/sgebbie/encryptinstallation.btrfs/blob/master/readme.md)...

3) ...And make one manual edit: change the invocation of "cryptsetup luksFormat" to add "--type=luks1". Because per [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019):

*The default LUKS (Linux Unified Key Setup) format used by the cryptsetup tool has changed since the release of 18.04 Bionic. 18.04 used version 1 ("luks1") but more recent Ubuntu releases default to version 2 ("luks2"). GRUB only supports version 1 so we have to be explicit in the commands we use or else GRUB will not be able to install to, or unlock, the encrypted device.*

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround that worked for me:

1. Install `ubiquity-frontend-gtk`
2. Run the command:

   ```
   ubiquity gtk_ui
   ```

   in the terminal

This is working fine in the Ubiquity GTK version.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this guide to manual partition with encryption and now I have dual boot, with full LVM encryption on the Linux side and BitLocker enabled on the Windows side: [link](https://www.mikekasberg.com/blog/2020/04/08/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-with-encryption.html)